Check URL response
I have a PowerShell script which open particular url with ArgumentList:
Start-Process -FilePath $viewer -ArgumentList '--ignore-certificate-errors --incognito --kiosk "https://192.168.1.1"'   

    do 
    {
        $processHMI = Get-Process chrome -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    until ($processHMI -ne $null)

How to make the http response check in the loop: if ok - stay on this url, if notok - display some html file?

PowerShell out of the box is unable to control Chrome / Edge (Chromium based browsers) out of the box in the same way as we could with internet explorer.
If you need to inspect the http responses inside the browser then you are very likely going to need to use Selenium Web Driver or Edge Web Driver to handle the responses and then essentially drive the browser to the html file / webpage location.

I was thinking what if you try to use PowerShell commands instead of trying to screen scrape from Google Chrome?
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://192.168.1.1" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StatusCode

This will return a 200 series response if the site is healthy and 300, 400, 500 if the site is not healthy.
